# using regular expressions in redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

This query works in mysql but I am not sure how to write the same query in redshift / postgresql.

```
update customer_Details set
customer_No = NULL
WHERE customer_No NOT REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{12}$'
```

Comment: replace `NOT REGEXP` with `!~`. You can shorten the regex pattern further to `^\d{12}$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [!~ operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE). Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE
    customer_details 
SET 
    customer_no = NULL 
WHERE 
    customer_No !~ '^[[:digit:]]{12}$';
```

Answer (score 2):

Redshift is basically a fork of postgres 8.3, and it uses postgres's regex syntax:

```
update customer_Details set
customer_No = NULL
WHERE customer_No ! ~ '^[0-9]{12}$'
```